# How to skip same duplicate key data when copy table

Tags: oracle, subquery, sql-insert, sqlbulkcopy

I have a table1(key is X, XX) looks like below:

```
x,y,xx,yy,xxx,yyy
```

I created a new table2 (key is code) as below:

```
code,name,xx,yy,xxx,yyy
```

Now I wan to copy all data in table1 to table2, and if met same code skip it,

```
x -> code
Y -> name
xx-> xx
yy -> yy
xxx -> xxx
yyy -> yyy
```

I used code as below to copy all data, I got error `00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"` because there is duplicated x in table1, but I am not sure how to skip duplicated X data, can you help me?

```
INSERT INTO table2 (code, name, xx, yy, xxx, yyy) 
SELECT x, y, xx, yy, xxx, yyy FROM table1
```

I tried this, I think it is not correct.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (code, name, xx, yy, xxx, yyy) 
SELECT DISTINCT x, y, xx, yy, xxx, yyy FROM table1
```

Comment: That answer has the same error `Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (table2_index) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.`

Comment: Then you need to look at the ON criteria, because you haven't them rigourous enough to meet the UNMATCHED filter.

Comment: I got what I need by `INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(table2, table2_index) */ INTO table2 (code, name, xx, yy, xxx, yyy) SELECT x, y, xx, yy, xxx, yyy FROM table1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### try this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (code, name, xx, yy, xxx, yyy) 
SELECT DISTINCT x, y, xx, yy, xxx, yyy FROM table1
where x not in (select code from table2)
```

OR

use hint  `/*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(table2, table2_index) */`

Comment: I got the same error:(

Comment: I got what I need `INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(table2, table2_index) */ INTO table2 (code, name, xx, yy, xxx, yyy) 
SELECT x, y, xx, yy, xxx, yyy FROM table1`

Comment: you can tick answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

You can try with cursor :

```
DECLARE
Cursor c1 is select code, name, xx, yy, xxx, yyy from table1;

for insertValue in c1
loop

insert into table2(code, name, xx, yy, xxx, yyy) values (insertValue.code, insertValue.name,insertValue.xx ... );

end loop;
```

Few insert will fail because of duplication , but rest should be inserted.

Or other option without cursor is :

```
BEGIN
 FOR insertValue IN (
 select code, name, xx, yy, xxx, yyy from table1 )
LOOP
insert into table2(code, name, xx, yy, xxx, yyy) values (insertValue.code, 
insertValue.name,insertValue.xx ... );  
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: is it possible not use cursor?

Comment: Error `CURSOR c1 IS SELECT
Error report -
Unknown Command`

Comment: if you dont want to use cursor , use below :
BEGIN
  FOR insertValue IN (
    SELECT code, name, xx, yy, xxx, yyy from table1
  )
  LOOP
    insert into table2(code, name, xx, yy, xxx, yyy) values (insertValue.code, insertValue.name,insertValue.xx ... );
  END LOOP;
END;
/